# Subsetting multiple columns that meet a criteria

Tags: r, subset

I'm currently using a dataset with 2000 rows and several columns, a sample of my data looks like this:

```
mydata <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)

Northing Parasite

 63900     4080
 78300     3090
 90200       0
 211100      0
 230200    3990
 239000      0
```

How would I subset these two rows from the whole data set, and have them meet the criteria: Northing > 200000 ?

Thanks for your help, I'm still quite new to r.

Answer (score 3):

With `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::filter(df, Northing > 200000)

  Northing Parasite
1   211100        0
2   230200     3990
3   239000        0
```

With base R:

```
df[df$Northing > 200000,]

  Northing Parasite
4   211100        0
5   230200     3990
6   239000        0
```

Another base R solution using `subset`:

```
subset(df, Northing > 200000)

  Northing Parasite
4   211100        0
5   230200     3990
6   239000        0
```